# JPQL query on sorting not taking column name directly on pageable sort value

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

```
@Query("SELECT new com.user.dto.response.EmployeeDetails(e.empName, e.empCode, e.address, e.locationCode,ul.userName, "
        + " ul.isLoginEnabled, ul.role) "
        + " FROM Employee e \r\n"
        + " LEFT JOIN UserLogin ul \r\n"
        + "     ON e.empCode = ul.empCode \r\n"
        + " WHERE (e.locationCode = :locationCode) AND AND (:role IS NULL OR e.role LIKE %:role%) \r\n"
        + " AND (:isLoginEnabled IS NULL OR ul.isLoginEnabled = :isLoginEnabled) \r\n")
Page<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetails(@Param("locationCode") String locationCode, @Param("role") String role,
        @Param("isLoginEnabled") Boolean isLoginEnabled, Pageable pageable);


@AllargsConstructor  //lombok
class EmployeeDetails{
    String empName;
    String empCode;
    String address;
    String locationCode;
    String userName;
    Boolean isLoginEnabled;
    String role;
}
```

so, when I pass,

<< empCode;desc >> in ?sort=empCode%2Cdesc, in query it is showing as 'e.empCode' desc

<< role;desc >> in ?sort=role%2Cdesc, in query it is showing as 'e.role' desc
 which is why it shows error as 'e.role' is not there in query

But, if I provide
<< u.role;desc >> in ?sort=u.role%2Cdesc, in query it is showing as 'u.role' desc and working

So, when I expose the API, UI will know only, empCode, empName, isLoginEnabled, role etc

How they are supposed to know when to pass "ul." as prefix or not.

Is there any fix?

I tried to give all constructor value with alias, still it is not considering. it is always calling "e.colName asc/ desc"

Answer (score 0):

You could use `as role` in your query `.. new package.EmployeeDetails(..., ul.role as role )`

Note: it should be `Page<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetails` and not `Page<RoleListDto> getEmployeeDetails`

simplified example using Kotlin

```
@Entity data class User(@Id val account : String, val name : String)
@Entity data class Email(@Id val email : String, @ManyToOne val user : User)

data class UserEmail(val name:String, val email:String)

interface UserRepo : PagingAndSortingRepository<User, String>

interface EmailRepo : PagingAndSortingRepository<Email, String> {

    //use 'e.user.name as name' in query,  this allows us to make
    //requests like /emails?sort=name,asc instead of  /emails?sort=user.name,asc 
    @Query("select new so.demo.UserEmail( e.user.name as name, e.email) from Email e" )
    fun findAllUserEmail(pageable: Pageable) : Page<UserEmail>
}

@RestController
class ApiController (private val userRepo : UserRepo, private val emailRepo: EmailRepo){
    @GetMapping("/emails")
    fun all(pageable: Pageable) = emailRepo.findAllUserEmail(pageable)
}
```

example code available on [github](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/jpa-pageable-custom-object)

Comment: I tried 'as' already still it's calling e.role. I have mentioned in my query saying I tried 'alias'

Comment: `Page<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetails` versus `Page<RoleListDto> getEmployeeDetails` ?

Comment: sorry it's EmployeeDetails, I copied it to dummy variables, and there I missed

Comment: have a look at my example on github, using an alias should work

Comment: Scneario-1. Where I renamed allias for same entity of repo in Join "e.empName as name", called "name, asc", it throws "No property roleCodes found for type name". It is only catching names of field which are of same repository. I have written in employee repository. So, all field of employee DAO is working. For "ul.isLoginEnabled", "ul.isLoginEnabled,desc" it thows "No property ul found for type name", For "ul.isLoginEnabled as isLogin", "isLogin,desc" it throws "No property isLogin found for type name"

Comment: It works for the field of same repository which in my case is employee repository. So, fields for UserLogin is not working somehow is what I concluded

Comment: with `select new com.user.dto.response.EmployeeDetails(e.empName, e.empCode, e.address, e.locationCode as locationCode,ul.userName as userName, ul.isLoginEnabled as isLoginEnabled , ul.role as role) .......` you should not need to use prefix _ul_ in _?sort=..._

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("SELECT e "
        + " FROM Employee e "
        + " LEFT JOIN UserLogin ul "
        + "     ON e.empCode = ul.emp_code "
        + " WHERE (e.location_code = :locationCode) AND (:role IS NULL OR e.role LIKE %:role%) "
        + " AND (:is_login_enabled IS NULL OR ul.is_login_enabled = :isLoginEnabled)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeDetails(@Param("locationCode") String locationCode, @Param("role") String role,
        @Param("isLoginEnabled") Boolean isLoginEnabled, Pageable pageable);




@AllargsConstructor  //lombok
class EmployeeDetails{
    @Column(name = "emp_name")
    String empName;

    @Column(name = "emp_code")
    String empCode;

    @Column(name = "address")
    String address;

    @Column(name = "location_code")
    String locationCode;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    String userName;

    @Column(name = "is_login_enabled")
    Boolean isLoginEnabled;

    @Column(name = "role")
    String role;
```

The above code might help.

Comment: How this code is different from mine? And why you wrote native query?